# ajaxtool kit - Html editor tools not displayed

Tags: asp.net, ajax, controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have installed ajaxtoolkit version 4.5 and included below lines in the config under controls tag

```html
<add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit"
                    namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
                    assembly="AjaxControlToolKit"/>
```

```html
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" Width="300" Height="400"/>
```

if i use html editor control getting the below error in IE9

0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

and in chrome the editor is displayed with no tools in it.

Please help to resolve this

Comment: Try <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" /> instead of ajax toolkit script manager.

Comment: tried that too... :(

Comment: I think you are installed ajaxtoolkit version 4.5 in dotnet framework 4.0...Please try to install ajaxtoolkit version 4.0...

Comment: i have dot framework 4.5 only

Comment: Please reference ajaxtoolkit DLL in your website/application and then try??

Comment: alternatively you can use ckeditor. :)  http://ckeditor.com/demo

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code like this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

HTML Markup:

```
<cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" Width="300" Height="400"/>
```

You can save your HTMLEditor content in database like this:

```
string lsPageContent = Server.HtmlEncode(Editor1.Content);
Insert into [TableName] (PageContent) Values ('" + lsPageContent + "');
```

and fetch page content like this:

```
Editor1.Content = Server.HtmlDecode(YourcolumnValue);
```

Comment: Unknown server tag 'cc1:ToolkitScriptManager'.

Comment: Did you made same changes which I mention above?? One more thing, can you please try to build your website/application?

Comment: It's very strange Kate. Finally I suggest you to remove this current toolkit and install version 4.0 in your current dotnet framework 4.5.

Comment: okay..many thanks to you :) one more dbt....is it possible to implement wiki editable functionality with this html editor tool??i mean..i need to edit my existing html page and once i click save button, the content has to be saved and displayed in the same page

Comment: Yes it is possible with this control. You can create HTML content of your page in this control and save it in your database table with Server.HtmlEncode(Editor1.Text) and when get back it on your page, use Server.HtmlDecode(YourTableField).

Comment: cool :) could you pls share some sample code for this if possible ..im really new to this

Comment: I have added in my answer. Please check.